# NightmareJS & Electron on Elastic Beanstalk - Permission Denied

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, electron, nightmare

I am trying to run NightmareJS on Elastic Beanstalk and I keep having an issue with Electron.

Error: EACCES: permission denied, mkdir '/tmp/deployment/application/node_modules/electron/electron-tmp-download-2233-1478789913678'

Here are the full logs: 
https://gist.github.com/QuentinDela/49e824c5889e14e899eafbe850d23055

Would you have any ideas on how to fix this? 
Thanks,

Answer (score 1):

You're failing due to a hook you're using (probably the file .ebextensions/50npm.sh or wherever your config says it is):

> [2016-11-10T14:58:33.905Z] INFO  [1993]  - [Application deployment
>   alexaskillstore-crawler2Version@1/StartupStage0/AppDeployPreHook/50npm.sh]
>   : Activity failed.